# \maketitle undefined control sequence{with ctex}

Tags: titles, ctex

I want to type Chinese in my report but I have some problem with my code. Once I add `\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}` in the file the compiler will complain with the message `undefined control sequence \maketitle`. Is there any solution to this so-called 'undefined' problem? Or is there any alternative to type Chinese in my report?

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{listings}

\title{综合实验试验报告}
\author{}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\begin{lstlisting}
 8048b36:   68 d0 a0 04 08          push   $0x804a0d0
 8048b3b:   ff 74 24 1c             pushl  0x1c(%esp)
 8048b3f:   e8 6f 05 00 00          call   80490b3 <strings_not_equal>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The code works on my laptop. You may want to check if you have installed CTeX from the beginning. There will be weird problems with Chinese if you did not install the whole CTeX bundle from the very beginning. The other thing you might want to check quickly is to try to remove the option `UTF8` for package `ctex` and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: It turns out that I should use XeLatex instead of pdfLatex to compile this file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a matter of using the right compiler.